# Reduction of multiple answers to single variable

Tags: dataset, dimensionality-reduction

The questionnaire for the data is [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/gvu/user_surveys/survey-1997-10/questions/general.html)

The first question takes multiple entry for the same question, I want to reduce this to a single variable. How do I do it?

The clean data is available [here](http://wikisend.com/download/586046/DataRaw.arff).
NB: The Column CompuPlat has missing values.

part of dataset

`CMFam CMHobb  CMNone  CMOther CMPol   CMProf  CMRel
0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   1   0
1   0   0   0   0   1   1
Community Membership_Family
Community Membership_Hobbies
Community Membership_None
Community Membership_Other
Community Membership_Political
Community Membership_Professional
Community Membership_Religious
Community Membership_Support`

I want to club all of them in a variable CM

Comment: Could you paste the head of the cleaned data in the question itself? Also, what do you mean by reducing this to a single variable? If you can, please provide some more context. Examples might help too.

Comment: Say I have put up a question to get replies for 5 disabilities, a respondent has 3 disabilities and there are multiple cases like this. How do I club all of them in a single categorical variable representing these disabilities?

Answer (score 2):

The variable represents the answer to the first question.

One straightforward way is to allow for all possible categories in this variable. For example, if there are 5 options in this answer, you will have to treat it as a categorical variable with 2^5 = 32 categories.

However, the number of categories increase exponentially with the number of options (check boxes) provided for the answer. In that case, it might be better to restrict the number of categories to, for example, 5. This can be done by leaving the top 4 choices/ options (by count) as they are and treating every other choice as "other".

Comment: The issue becomes bigger when I have 11 such variables

Comment: Agreed. It becomes more and more complicated as the number of choices/ options increase. But you choose to restrict the number of categories to, for example, 5. This can be done by using the top 4 choices/ options as they are and treating everything else as "other".

Comment: Any other way out?

Comment: I will probably edit my answer with the above comment.

Comment: How do I figure out the top 4 choices?

Comment: Collect data first and then use the collected data to figure out the top 4 choices by count.

Comment: As pointed above, trying to merge those multiple variables into one becomes more complicated as the number of dummy variables rises. For modelling purposes, it is often useful to keep those variables as dummy variables. If some combinations of those dummies are very common, then you can explore those effect by using interactions in your model. Whether you want to reduce those variables into a composite will depend on the type of analysis you plan on conducting on the resulting data.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, one easy solution would be to concatenate the bits together and make a 7-bit binary sequence then convert it to integer. So, for your sample dataset quoted in the question you would get:

`CM
16
0
98
8
6
67`